# SQL AGENT JOB :refused because the job is already running from a request by Schedule 34 (Every Minute)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-agent-job

> Message [000] Request to run job Process*******DataSetLastTwoDays
>   (********) refused because the job is already running from a request
>   by Schedule 34 (Every Minute)

Could anyone help with the above error? This is an SQL Server Agent job that is meant to refresh every 2 minutes. After working for a couple of days, it stops running and causes other jobs depending on this to fail.

NB: It is a partitioning made in SSAS (Tabular mode).

Comment: The error suggest that the job is already running, so it's taking longer than the time between schedules. You can't start a task if it's already running; hence the failure.

Comment: As already mentioned you need to do some investigation - go and open up the job log and see what's happening.

Comment: Thank you Larnu. The problem is Its perfectly OK for couple of days until it hits the point when it start giving the error. Hence causing other jobs depending on it to fail

Comment: Then you need to work out why it's taking longer. every couple of days.